# Workbox: old version not changing to new version

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I am using workbox to cache my single page application. My webpack settings looks as follows:

```
new workboxPlugin({
    globDirectory: dist,
    globPatterns: ['**/*.js', '**/*.html'],
    swDest: path.join(dist, 'sw.js'),
    clientsClaim: true,
    skipWaiting: true,  
    }),
```

For the most part it works. However sometimes some devices refuse to update. 
One scenario:

1. I refresh the page a few times with ctrl - F5. But the new version does not appear
2. I open chrome development tools and do a ctrl - F5. Then it works
3. If I press normal F5 (with or without devtools open) it reverts to the previous version of the application. In addition, if I close the dev tools and press ctrl - F5 it also reverts.

Other devices upgrade flawlessly.

Comment: See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1603